# What's best way to prevent duplicating object in Realm?

Tags: ios, database, realm

I have next error: Attempting to create an object of type 'TypeId' with an existing primary key value '96292'.
And I got crash after this.

Comment: You have to fetch the object with the `TypeID` out, then modify it, you cannot create duplicate of object that have primary key

Comment: Having the same primary key value. Updating the object if exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `String` type for the primary key instead of the `Int` type, and use UUID for each object, then you could avoid the duplicated keys.

```
class AModel: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

**Alternatively**, if you want to use Int, and you are sure about that there is only one object will be created in a second, you could use timestamp value to avoid the situation too:

```
class AModel: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

**Agree** with @Tj3n and @EpicPandaForce's opinions, updating it if it's not a new object actually.